# Select the first item in combobox when AddNewRow form appears in GridView - Devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project and I have tried to initialize a combobox with his first item, like index 0.

The only thing that I have done is to set an static value.

```
settings.InitNewRow = (sender, e) =>
{            
    e.NewValues["ProductId"] = 2;
};
```

How can I select the first element if I don't know the Id code?

Answer (score 0):

```
settings.InitNewRow = (sender, e) =>
{
    e.NewValues["ProductId"] = items[0].Id; //here items is the data source and it should be populated before the execution of this line.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've defined a static class with a method that return the Products. Then in the view I invoke the method and select the Id of the first element.

```
settings.InitNewRow = (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (MyProject.Util.Catalogs.Products().Count > 0)
        {
            e.NewValues["ProductId"] = MyProject.Util.Catalogs.Products().First().Id;
        }

    };
```